# React JS : Calling Child component method within parent component (React with typescript)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, callback, setstate, react-component

I am trying to create a custom number picker component and trying to add it to the components wherever it is needed. But When I am trying to fetch the number picker value in the Parent component , I am getting the older value .
Can someone help me with this?

### Number Picker Component

```
import * as React from "react";

interface IState {
  value: number;
}

interface IProps {
  setValue(val: number): void;
}

class NumberPicker extends React.Component<IProps, IState> {
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: 0
    };
  }

  public doDecrement = () =>
    // DECREMENT CODE
    {
      if (this.state.value < 1) {
        console.log("LESS THAN O");
      } else {
        this.setState({
          value: this.state.value - 1
        });
        this.props.setValue(this.state.value);
      }
    };

  public doIncrement = () =>
    // INCREMENT CODE
    {
      this.setState({
        value: this.state.value + 1
      });
      this.props.setValue(this.state.value);
    };

  public handleChange = (
    e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement> // CHANGE HANDLER
  ) => {
    const val = parseInt(e.target.value);
    this.setState({ value: val });
  };

  public render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button
          onClick={this.doDecrement}
          className="fa fa-minus fa-inverse fa-2x"
        />
        <input
          type="text"
          className="number"
          value={this.state.value}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
        <button
          onClick={this.doIncrement}
          className="fa fa-plus fa-inverse fa-2x"
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default NumberPicker;
```

### PARENT COMPONENT CODE

```
import * as React from "react";
import NumberPicker from "./NumberPicker";

interface IState {
  val: number;
}

interface IProps {}

class Parent extends React.Component<IProps, IState> {
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      val: 0
    };
  }

  handleVal = (value: number) => {
    this.setState({ val: value }, () => console.log(this.state.val));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      //Some fields along with the below numberpicker
      <NumberPicker setValue={this.handleVal} />
    );
  }
}

export default Parent;
```

I have tried using setState's callback function as well, but it does not seem to be working . Parent component always shows the older value.How will I get the updated value of the NumberPicker inside parent?
Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React's `setState` is asynchronous, and because of that `this.props.setValue` function is going to be called before `setState` has updated your state in child Numberpicker component. This is why an old value is passed to the parent component.

Instead you can call `this.props.setValue` inside `setState`'s callback function.

```js
 public doIncrement = () =>
    // INCREMENT CODE
    {
      this.setState({
        value: this.state.value + 1
      }, () => {
              this.props.setValue(this.state.value);
         });

    };
```

```js
public doDecrement = () =>
    // DECREMENT CODE
    {
      if (this.state.value < 1) {
        console.log("LESS THAN O");
      } else {
        this.setState({
          value: this.state.value - 1
        }, () => {
              this.props.setValue(this.state.value);
           });
      }
    };
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks much

Answer (score 0):

setState is not a synchrounous function. So when you are calling the callback from parent you are calling it with old state value, because new value will be set sometime in future. You can call the callback with the same value you are setting to state: this.state.value - 1 or this.state.value + 1. It should work as expected. I also recommend to read [thinking in react](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html) for better intuition about where you should hold your state.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation

Answer (score 0):

Don't use state for passing values in callback, you can do like:-

```
  handleChange = (
    e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement> // CHANGE HANDLER
  ) => {
    const val = parseInt(e.target.value);
    // this.setState({ value: val });
    this.props.setValue(val);
  };
```

i hope it helps!